# Is there an easy way of finding all relations (ForeignKey/ManyToManyField/OneToOneField) to the model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `File` model I'd like to know which instances of this model aren't used in any other models in my DB so I can safely delete them. The sample models look like this:

```
class File(models.Model):
    origin = models.FileField()

class Doc(models.Model):
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File)

class Company(models.Model):
    logo = models.ForeignKey(File)

class FileInfo(models.Model):
    file = models.OneToOneField(File)
```

Also, the solution should be dynamic so that it will work without modifications in cases when new links to the File model added.

I tried looping over `model._meta.fields`, checking `field.rel.to` but failed to produce a working version.

Answer (score 0):

You can just filter them:

```
File.objects.filter(file_info__isnull=True, doc__isnull=True, logo__isnull=True).delete()
```

Comment: I was looking for `Also, the solution should be dynamic so that it will work without modifications in cases when new links to the File model added.`

Comment: Dynamic is cool, but you're deleting files and it is the best way to loose all your files after an update.